# Who is this character helping Iron Man in Marvel's "What If...?" series?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, marvel-what-if-2021

Marvel just released a trailer for its upcoming *What If...?* Disney+ series:

At 0:15, a guy throws away a Stark Industry bomb which had injured Tony Stark back in 2008. Who is this guy?

Comment: And here I thought it hat to be [Munroe](https://what-if.xkcd.com/archive/)...

Comment: You can see his name tag on his jacket says Killmonger

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is Erik Stevens (N'Jadaka), AKA Killmonger, you'll note that his vest has his name on it:

[image: Killmonger from the trailer with a nametag on his body armour]

We saw him in *Black Panther* where he wore very similar clothes to what we see in the trailer.

[image: Close on Erik as seen in BP]

An article on The Illuminerdi has some details on this story, click through to see the full thing:

> Our sources have informed us that Michael B. Jordan’s Erik Stevens/Killmonger will be a key player in an episode of Marvel Studios’ What If…?. However, rather than going after the throne of Wakanda, Stevens will go international thanks to a new friendship with Tony Stark.
>
> <sub>[The Illuminerdi, NEW DETAILS FOR KILLMONGER’S EPISODE OF WHAT IF…?: EXCLUSIVE](https://www.theilluminerdi.com/2021/06/17/killmonger-what-if/)</sub>

As noted by RogueJedi it is worth mentioning that Erik served for the SEALs in Afghanistan and also fought in Iraq as well as other places so it isn't out of the ordinary for him to be there.

> **Everett K. Ross:** Erik Stevens. Graduated Annapolis aged nineteen, MIT for grad school. Joined the SEALs and went straight to Afghanistan, where he wrapped up confirmed kills like it was a video game. Started calling him Killmonger. He joined a J-SOC ghost unit, now these guys are serious, they would drop off the grid so they could commit assassinations and take down governments.
>
> <sub>*Black Panther*</sub>

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that it's stated in *Black Panther* that he served in Afghanistan

Comment: I mean, even without the name badge, it's still pretty obviously him.  The hair alone would be enough, but that outfit is pretty clearly a match.  And it's not some version from the comics, the artists were definitely looking at Michael B. Jordan when they made that.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Oh of course, that's why I included both. I believe the MCU actors are doing the voice over work as well so it is properly tied in.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Indeed, *every* character in the show is clearly based on (and seems to be voiced by, where possible) their real-life actors.

Comment: @TylerH Tony sounded off, was that RDJ?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I can't say for sure, but maybe? He is still alive and it would mean more money for him so it's quite likely, though there is a lot of VA talent who sounds close enough for animated content. When I said "where possible" I was thinking mostly of Chadwick Boseman. Though the person voicing Vision is clearly not Paul Bettany either.

Comment: @TylerH That *is* Boseman though (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chadwick_Boseman#Filmography)

Comment: I guess Wiki lists those that are being voiced by their actors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_If...%3F_(TV_series), of which Tony isn't one (but Thor is, who also sounded off to me). It's ambiguous whether Vision is or isn't voiced by Bettany.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Wow, that's surprising. I'm guessing he will have a different VA for most of his content though, especially if it runs more than one series. Personally I thought Thor sounded spot on. Paul Bettany's Wiki page has no info on this show FWIW https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Bettany#Television

Comment: @TylerH Yeah there were a lot of Reddit comments about it being his final performance.

Answer (score 16):

IGN tweeted about this. It is Killmonger.

> What if… Killmonger saved Tony Stark? What if Peggy Carter became Captain Carter? What if Black Panther was a Ravager?
>
> Marvel’s animated series What If…? Hits Disney+ starting August 11.

https://twitter.com/IGN/status/1413171917729718272

Answer (score 2):

I just saw a few seconds of this from another source; I'm pretty sure that's Killmonger (though I presume he's not going by that name with this kind of heroism).

Comment: I'm not sure saving the life of a billionaire weapons manufacturer necessarily counts as heroism if you are a mercenary.

Comment: See my updated answer, if you look closely he has a "Killmonger" name badge on his vest.